# How do I program a hardware button on my laptop?

Tags: button-remapping

So I have a set of touch screen buttons on the top of my laptop's keyboard, (one turns on power save mode, one disables/enables the mouse touch pad, one toggles the wifi adapter, and two turns the volume up/down).

However there's another one that opened a file backup utility that came with my laptop. Since I bought my laptop, I've uninstalled that utility, rendering this button useless.

Would it be possible to reprogram that button to open another file or program on my computer? And if so, what are the requirements and how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you prepared to write code to make it work? If not, it's a superuser.com question...

Comment: well it depends on what language i would have to write it in, and what do you mean by superuser.com question?

Comment: Assuming your using windows but if so please let us know what version or what other OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Keyboard Remap tool from the Microsoft toys package, you might want to read the following first.

http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm